# Cinelerra: how do I add comments to media clips (resources window)?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, video-editing

I have imported some clips, which are named MOV001, MOV002, etc. If I switch the Resources window view mode to "text", I can see there are two columns: Title and Comments. I can't figure out how to input a string that would be displayed in the Comments column alongside the clip file name.

The reason I want to do that is to briefly describe the clips content without having to rename the on-disk file.

I right-clicked on a clip and then on the "Info" menu item, but couldn't see any "Comments" field in there.

The [Cinelerra manual page about the Resources window](http://cinelerra.org/docs/split_manual_en/cinelerra_cv_manual_en_10.html) doesn't mention the Comments column.

Google didn't provide any useful information either.

(For the record I'm using Cinelerra CV 2.2 on Ubuntu Linux 12.04.)

Comment: I noticed there isn't a Cinelerra tag yet. I think creating one would be useful, as there's already a bunch of Cinelerra-related questions here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Raffaella Traniello has an [excellent tutorial](http://www.g-raffa.eu/Cinelerra/HOWTO/index.html) on Cinelerra. She kindly answered my question pointing me to [a bug report](http://bugs.cinelerra.org/ticket/535) which confirms the problem.

Unfortunately, that bug report is 4 years old as of this writing, which makes me think it's unlikely that it'll be fixed anytime soon.

Cinelerra 4.4 was released on 9/7/12. Since I'm using version 2.2, I should definitely give that a try. Unfortunately, it looks like that version is only provided as a source tarball, with a warning that code might need some tweaks to compile... O_o

EDIT: comments can be entered when creating "clips" out of media files; those comments can also be edited afterwards by right-clicking on the clip in the Resources window and selecting "Info" (clips are *not* media files).

Comment: http://deb-multimedia.org/ offers precompiled cinelerra-4.4 debian packages (haven't tested them though).